# wavesurfer.js play([start[, end]]) end not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, web-audio-api, recorder.js

I'm making a sampler with wavesurfer.js and recorder.js. everything is working smoothly except i can't adjust the loop length using play([start[, end]]).

```
wavesurfer.seekTo(1);
wavesurfer.play(1,2);
```

the seekto() method works fine but can't change the end of the loop.
I want to be able to start the sample at 1 second in and end 2 seconds in.

please help

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested the issue has been resolved and .seekTo() now works as expected